# implement playerVars parameters in angular app using @angular/youtube-player

Tags: angular, youtube-iframe-api

I am using @angular/youtube-player to render a video in angular app.
I need to play it on autoplay.
on reading the [docs](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/youtube-player/youtube-player.ts), I got the [configuration](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters.html?playerVersion=HTML5#Parameters)  to set it to autoplay.
but still somehow its not running..

here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-youtube-video-paifsc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)  link

pls help me to set the parameters

Comment: `[playerVars]="{'autplay': 1}"` should be the correct input, but it might be that you are using are version that doesn't support that yet.

Comment: i am using version 9.2.4

Comment: Please provide code here, links can be deleted.

Comment: Please think about others, who will view this question after 1 or 2 years

Answer (score 0):

this must be changed

```
[playerVars]="{'autplay': 1}"
```

to this

```
[playerVars]="{'autoplay': 1}"
```

in order to work as expected